Unable to send Email
Unable to send email using below code:
Getting error:
Error in sendEmailUsingTemplate: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, We don't recognize the field prefix Case. Associate a record that matches the prefix or update the template to remove the merge field from the body, subject, or letterhead.: []
18:22:43.0 (134834355)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[93]
Template Body:
Dear {{{Case.Supplied_First_Name__c}}},
Thank you for contacting us.
Kind regards,
{UserName}
public class CaseCalloutQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private Case c;
    private String serviceProvider;
    private String template;

    public CaseCalloutQueueable(Case c, String serviceProvider, String template) {
        this.c = c;
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        if (serviceProvider == 'Email') {
            sendEmailUsingTemplate(c, template);
        }   
    }

    private void sendEmailUsingTemplate(Case c, String templateName) {
        System.debug('templateName>>>'+templateName);
        if (c == null || String.isEmpty(templateName)) {
            System.debug('Case or template name is null/empty. Aborting email send.');
            return;
        }

        try {
            List<EmailTemplate> templates = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Id = :templateName LIMIT 1];
            System.debug('templates.size()>>>'+templates.size());
            if (templates.isEmpty()) {
                System.debug('No email template found with the name: ' + templateName);
                return;
            }

            EmailTemplate template = templates[0];

            if (String.isEmpty(c.SuppliedEmail)) {
                System.debug('Case does not have an email address.');
                return;
            }
            OrgWideEmailAddress owea;
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                owea = [select Id, DisplayName, Address from OrgWideEmailAddress where DisplayName =: System.Label.emailDisplayName limit 1];
            }
            System.debug('owea>>>'+owea);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            if(owea?.Id != null) {
                email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.Id);
            }
            email.setTargetObjectId(c.OwnerId);
            email.setTemplateId(template.Id);
            email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{c.SuppliedEmail});
            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            
            System.debug('email>>>'+email);

            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> { email });
            System.debug('results>>>'+results);

            if(results[0].success){
                system.debug('The email was sent successfully! ');

                EmailMessage newEmailMessage = new EmailMessage();
                newEmailMessage.Subject = template.Subject;
                newEmailMessage.HtmlBody = template.HtmlValue;
                newEmailMessage.Status = '3'; // '3' represents 'Sent' status
                newEmailMessage.ParentId = c.Id;
                newEmailMessage.ToAddress = c.SuppliedEmail;
                newEmailMessage.FromName = owea.DisplayName;
                newEmailMessage.FromAddress = owea.Address;
                Insert newEmailMessage;

                EmailMessageRelation emr = new EmailMessageRelation();
                emr.emailMessageId = newEmailMessage.id;
                emr.relationId = c.Id; // user id of the sender
                emr.relationType = 'FromAddress';
                insert emr;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error in Line: ' + e.getLineNumber());
            System.debug('Error in sendEmailUsingTemplate: ' + e.getMessage());
            System.debug('Stack trace: ' + e.getStackTraceString());
        }
    }
}


You need to add email.setWhatId(c.Id) to set the relationship that will resolve the Case reference.

I tried adding whatId, but getting error: Error in sendEmailUsingTemplate: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds.: [whatId, 500Pv000008gaSI]
